# SCISPACY - Maximum length exceeded

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am getting the following error while trying to use a spaCy pipeline for biomedical data.

```
ValueError: [E088] Text of length 36325726 exceeds the maximum of 1000000. The v2.x parser and NER models require roughly 1GB of temporary memory per 100,000 characters in the input. This means long texts may cause memory allocation errors. If you're not using the parser or NER, it's probably safe to increase the `nlp.max_length` limit. The limit is in the number of characters, so you can check whether your inputs are too long by checking `len(text)`.
```

Note: When I am reducing the size, it works fine. But, NLP is all about big data :) (mostly)

**Update:**
So, the ValueError is resolved. But SciSpacy is using too much processing power and thus forcing Kaggle Kernel to restart.

For now, I have split my dataset (1919 articles into 15 separate items), just to achieve the result.

But please let me know if there is some other way and if I am missing something. Here is the latest Kernel: [Cord-19](https://www.kaggle.com/psrajput/cord-19-nlp)

[image: spacy]

Comment: Are you using the NER? Seems like the error message has already provided you with a workaround. Otherwise, a bit more context might be necessary to provide you with a solution

Comment: It says in the error message that you can raise the limit but you can face memory issues depending on which parts of the pipeline you are using.

Comment: No @C.Nivs No, not NER. Its SCISPACY, a biomedical package of spacy.

Comment: @AnastasiiaIurshina Yeah saw that message and tried to implement it with

`# doc.max_length = 36325727`

But didn't work. Will commit the latest Kaggle version in 5 minutes. https://www.kaggle.com/psrajput/cord-19-nlp/

Comment: I have defined it as doc, not NLP. I made the latest commit in Kaggle, you can check it out and maybe fork.

Comment: `doc = biod.load() doc.max_length = 2000000` worked for me. For text length 833162 * 2.

Comment: @AnastasiiaIurshina Thanks, it works, now I face another problem. Updated my query.